# How to decrease deletion time in IBM db2

Tags: database, db2, sql-delete

We are using IBM db2, trying to delete 200000 data from different tables, using stored procedure invoked through java code.
It's taking 75+ hours to delete, suggest ways to optimize the deletion time.
we can't stop the log for the deletion.
we can't use the truncate feature.

Comment: Do you have a Db2-DBA?  This is a FAQ.  Any competent DBA will be able to ensure that the access-plan for the DELETE statement(s) is optimised , that the Db2-server logging configuration is optimised , that the I/O settings configuration of the Db2 server are optimised.   This is not programming. It is administration and configuration competence.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is one way

```
/*
 * Example of deleting X rows of data at a time from a table to avoid e.g. transaction log full on row organized talbes
 * 
 */

BEGIN
    DECLARE DONE  BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;  
    --
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' BEGIN SET DONE = TRUE; END;
    --
    WHILE NOT DONE
    DO
        DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COL1 = 'A' FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY)
        COMMIT;
    END WHILE;
END
```

You could also consider using MDC tables to allow "[rollout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0051901.html)" deletion, or other physical design optimizations